# Drive unicycle kinematics equations through the geometry

Tags: geometry, transformation, mathematical-modeling, kinematics, robotics

Consider a unicycle model as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948112/how-to-generalize-the-euclidean-unicycle-model). The unicycle dynamics in discrete-time can be written as:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
{x_{k + 1}} = {x_k} + \Delta {s_{k + 1}} \times \cos ({\theta _{k + 1}})\\
{x_{k + 1}} = {x_k} + \Delta {s_{k + 1}} \times \sin ({\theta _{k + 1}})\\
{\theta _{k + 1}} = {\theta _{k }} + \Delta {\theta _{k + 1}}
\end{array}
$$

However, some researchers have introduced an additional term to the argument of the trigonometric functions above; for example see: [Autonomous Land Vehicles: Steps towards Service Robots By Karsten Berns, and Ewald Puttkamer](https://books.google.com/books?id=iEYnnQeOaaIC&pg=PA29)

$$
\begin{array}{l}
{x_{k + 1}} = {x_k} + \Delta {s_{k + 1}} \times \cos ({\theta _{k }} + \frac{{\Delta {\theta _{k + 1}}}}{2})\\
{x_{k + 1}} = {x_k} + \Delta {s_{k + 1}} \times \sin ({\theta _{k }} + \frac{{\Delta {\theta _{k + 1}}}}{2})\\
{\theta _{k + 1}} = {\theta _{k }} + \Delta {\theta _{k + 1}}
\end{array}
$$

I was wondering which one is geometrically correct? In other words, how we can show that $\cos ({\theta _k} + \frac{{\Delta {\theta _{k + 1}}}}{2}) = \cos ({\theta _{k + 1}})$?

According to the following figure, we have

$$
\Delta {x_{k + 1}} = \Delta {s_{k + 1}} \times \sin (\frac{{\Delta {\theta _{k + 1}}}}{2})
$$

This may seem to be a strange result, since we said that

$$
\Delta {x_{k + 1}} = \Delta {s_{k + 1}} \times \cos ({\theta _{k + 1}} + \frac{{\Delta {\theta _{k + 1}}}}{2})
$$

---

[image: Autonomous Land Vehicles: Steps towards Service Robots By Karsten Berns, Ewald Puttkamer]

Comment: It is just a matter of which discretisation scheme you are following.  The midpoint rule has better local truncation error than the one-sided version but there is of course a small price to pay.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you for your comment. Could you please provide some references on what you mean by "one-sided " and "midpoint " discretization?

Comment: Regardless of the methods, we can use for the discretization of ODEs, my focus is on the derivation of the discrtized equations based on the geometry of the motion depicted above.